# Creating a JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I am making a JSON request to server using Java. Here is the following parameters.

```
{method:'SearchBySearchConfiguration',params:[{{SearchCriteria:'%arriva',
 IsAccountSearch:true,IsContactSearch:false,SearchByName:true,SearchByAddress:false
 CRMTextValues:[], CRMCurrencyValues:[]}]}
```

I could do this way.

```
 JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
 json.put("method", "SearchBySearchConfiguration");
```

How do I add the rest of params, in name-value pair to JSON object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
  json.put("method", "SearchBySearchConfiguration"); 
  JSONArray paramsArr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject arrobj = new JSONOject();
      arrobj.put("SearchCriteria","%arriva");
      arrobj.put("IsAccountSearch","true");
      arrobj.put("IsContactSearch","false");
      arrobj.put("SearchByName","true");
      arrobj.put("SearchByAddress","false");
      arrobj.put("CRMTextValues",new JSONArray());
      arrobj.put("CRMCurrencyValues",new JSONArray());
    paramsArr.put(arrobj);
  json.put("params",paramsArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of is using the [org.json](http://www.json.org/) library. I wrote a sample to build part of your request object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("method", "SearchBySearchConfiguration");

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject innerRecord = new JSONObject();
    innerRecord.put("SearchCriteria", "%arriva");
    innerRecord.put("IsAccountSearch", true);

    jsonArray.put(innerRecord);
    jsonObject.put("params",jsonArray);

    System.out.println("jsonObject :"+jsonObject);

}
```

The output is :

```
jsonObject :{"method":"SearchBySearchConfiguration","params":[{"IsAccountSearch":true,"SearchCriteria":"%arriva"}]}
```

Another technique would be to build Java objects that resemble your request structure. You can then convert it into json using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) library's ObjectMapper class.

In both cases once you get the json string, you can directly write it into the request body.

Answer (score 0):

The you can create `JSONArray` and put that array in `JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

Its Better to use [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for this.

First you need to create classs with following members :

```
public class TestClass{

    private String method;
    private ParamClass params;


    }
public class ParamClass{
    private String SearchCriteria;
    private boolean IsAccountSearch;
    private boolean IsContactSearch;
    private boolean SearchByName;
    private boolean SearchByAddress;
    private String[] CRMTextValues;
    private String[] CRMCurrencyValues;
}
```

Usage :

Serializing :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();    
String jsonString = gson.toJson(testClassObject);
```

Deserializing :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
TestClass testClassObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString , TestClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

**See this below example, where a JSONArray is returned and then how i am converting it in JSONObject form...**

```
public JSONArray go() throws IOException, JSONException {

JSONArray json = readJsonFromUrl("http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/AppData.aspx");

return json;
 }


JSONArray jarr;

for(int i=0 ; i<jarr.length() ; i++){

JSONObject jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);

String mainText = new String();
String provText = new String();
String couText = new String();      

try{

mainText = jobj.getString("Overview");
System.out.println(mainText);
}catch(Exception ex){}

try{

JSONObject jProv = jobj.getJSONObject("Provider");
provText = jProv.getString("Name");
System.out.println(provText);
}catch(Exception ex){}



try{                

JSONObject jCou = jobj.getJSONObject("Counterparty");
couText = jCou.getString("Value");
System.out.println(couText);
}catch(Exception ex){}
```

**Jackson is a very efficient to do JSON Parsing**

**See this link:**

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

**Gson is provided by google which is also a good way to handle JSON.**

Answer (score 0):

To add **params**, `JSONArray` is used.
Inside params, we use `JSONObject` to add data such as SearchByAddress, IsAccountSearch ..etc.
 Reference http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

```
package com.test.json;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

public class JsonSimpleExample {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("method", "SearchBySearchConfiguration");

    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject innerObj = new JSONObject();

    innerObj.put("SearchCriteria","%arriva" );
    innerObj.put("IsAccountSearch",true);
    innerObj.put("IsContactSearch",false);
    innerObj.put("SearchByName",true);
    innerObj.put("SearchByAddress",false);
    innerObj.put("CRMTextValues",new JSONArray());
    innerObj.put("CRMCurrencyValues",new JSONArray());

    list.add(innerObj);

    obj.put("params", list);
    System.out.print(obj);

     }

}
```